# libudev-dev is not installed in debian

Tags: linux, debian, nfc, pcsc, lib-nfc

I have to install pcsc-lite 1.8.13 on my debian-sid operating system.

When I run :/configure, I encounter "install libudev-dev" error.

I have installed libudev-dev with this command: "sudo apt-get instal libudev-dev".

Still, I get the same missing libudev-dev error.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: so, how you fixed it?

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't remember. It was 3 years ago. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing pkg-config (sudo apt install pkg-config)